# Prompt for credentials on every access to a document library

Tags: 2013, document-library, windows-authentication, custom-login-page

I need some assistance to build the below:

I'm using SharePoint 2013 web application (windows authentication) and we need that each time we click on the document library link to appear a popup windows and request to add the username & password of the active directory.

I am facing problem since the user was granted permission on the site & the document library list.... but the contradiction is how I can add a script to request to add his AD access once his clicking on the document list tab

Please help me and give me details or references link

On another way I mean that we need to implement a custom login as popup to request to add the Active directory user & password each time I try to open the document library list of my intranet site

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

Why create a custom login page when you can achieve this by breaking the inheritance permission on that document library.

Break the inheritance permission on the document library and grant permission to only those users/groups that should have access to that library. Users/groups not granted access to this document library, will pop-up window asking for credentials when they try to access this library.

For your reference:
[SharePoint 2013: Break Document Library Permissions Inheritance](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18203.sharepoint-2013-break-document-library-permissions-inheritance.aspx)

Comment: Yes I know that ...but the document library has confidential information and the sales man needs that each time he click on the link it will ask him for the credential for more security (for example: if the IT guys work on his laptop he cannot login to that page since he need the password ? ) ... I know its something weird but I need to do it ?? Any help

Answer (score 0):

Is there anyone out there done this?, I have the same scenario with a client and want to know if I achieve this even on SharePoint Online?

I found an [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618951/force-sharepoint-to-ask-for-authentication) for a workaround which is creating a new zone with FBA and secure this Document Library with it, so the users first authenticate by AD and then by FBA when they try to reach the Document Library.